# Flutter App Building Release Problem (Firestore)

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

The App is working fire on Debug mode but when I run "flutter build appbundle"

It give's me this error
But **Flutter Build Apk** working fine

My Minimum SDK is 23

**My dependencies:**

> firebase_core: ^0.4.2+1  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.10+2  firebase_auth:
>   ^0.15.0+1

````
Initializing gradle...                                              1.3s
Resolving dependencies...                                          22.9s
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.12.10+2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.12.10+2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...

Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... Done                       143.2s (!)
Gradle build failed to produce an Android bundle package.
PS E:\VScodeFlutter\chatapp_x>  ```
````